# How to stop finder from expanding windows and covering folders on the left?

Tags: finder, windows, icon

It didn't happen with older OS systems, but it does with my M1.

If I show items as icons in the finder, sometimes the window will enlarge and expand horizontally, covering up the folders on the hard left, which confuses me as I usually need to see the exact path to the directory. If I then change the view mode and then go back to icons, it sets it how I'd like it.

Basically, I'd like to have it like in case n.2 (so that I can see all folders), not n. 1.

Is there a way to make it stay like that all the time?[image]

Comment: I don't think there has been a change in the Finder's behaviour for decades, but you can show the entire file path from the View menu > "Show Path Bar". The path is interactive (you can click on each folder). Also, Command Up arrow will navigate to the parent folder, even if you can't see it.

Comment: all right, that's actually a good solution so thank you. However, I never encountered this specific behaviour with my old Macs. With another computer that I used recently (Mac mini 2018, OS Catalina), it didn't happen. I don't know why it suddenly does it with my Macbook M1.

Comment: I've definitely observed this on a 2018 Mini.

Comment: all right, well, I was hoping there was a way to keep it like in the second case. anyway, thank you!